# Google Places API Autocomplete Not Showing Results

Tags: reactjs, google-places-api

In my React application. I'm using the Google Places API Autocomplete so users will be able to type their location and their city/state/country info will be automatically filled in, but I'm getting a problem I can't solve.

```
const autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
```

When I don't specify options to the second parameter. Everything works good but I only want to return the user's city, state, and country but when I specify a type. The autocomplete don't even show me results.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that there could be something wrong when declaring your option object. But I can't exactly say without having a look at your code.

But this is the example provided by google in their google Maps Api. I hope that this will solve your problem.

```
var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
  new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8902, 151.1759),
  new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8474, 151.2631));

var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
var options = {
  types: ['(cities)'],
  componentRestrictions: {country: 'fr'} // show only results for country France
};

autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
```

For more details you can refer google maps API
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete